# 2008 Jeep Wrangler - Suspension squeaks

Tags: noise, suspension, jeep, wrangler

The suspension on my 2008 Jeep Wrangler squeaks when I hit a low spot (maybe 4-6" from the grade), even at slow (<10 mph) speeds.

Where can I lubricate or what should I check to eliminate this squeaking?

Comment: I'm curious to know whether or not you get the full service lube or you do it yourself. Suspension systems I've had typically have multiple lubrication points requiring periodic greasing. The full service lube's you get from the quick-lube type places are supposed to hit all these spots, but I would be suspicious of ... pretty much anybody I don't know and approve of doing anything to my vehicle. So, I guess I'm asking if you know whether or not the suspension has had proper periodic maintenance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claptrap is on the money with grease points, but many modern cars don't have them, and I can't speak to how the Wrangler is setup. That is the perfect starting point, though.

The next step would be to spray down all the rubber mounting points (suspension bushings, shock mounts, etc) with white lithium grease to see if that quiets it down at all. I fear that a normal spray bottle won't be able to get into the 'inside' surfaces of the rubber parts that are causing the squeaks. That leaves you with the final option of unbolting the problem elements so that you can rub some grease on the rubber surfaces. The downside with this solution is that suspension can be very dangerous if you loosen the wrong bolt. In fact, it can be *deadly*.

So, I would recommend trying the grease points, and the white lithium grease options before proceeding any further. Hopefully, that fixes the issue.

Comment: Check the swaybar bushings first, they probably need lubrication.   That's a very common issue as they're typically located in a place where the lube gets washed out of them pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

I have three Wranglers, and there are plenty of places on them to squeak, and not all of them have grease nipples.

The most common places that will cause a squeak on the Wrangler, in order of likeliness)

- Track Bar bushings (rubber bushings, no grease point)
- Tie rod ends at the axle (usually grease points at both ends)
- Drag Link (usually greasable at both ends)
- Lower Control arm mounts (rubber bushings at both ends, not greasable)
- Upper Control arm mounts (rubber bushings at both ends, not greasable)
- Sway bar links (rubber bushings at both ends, not greasable)
- Sway bar bushings (located on the frame, not greasable)
- Lower Shock mounts (rubber busings, not greasable)
- Shocks (Could be dirt behind the boot, or your shocks are shot)
- Springs can sometimes rub against the spring perch causing a squeak.
- Drive shaft boot

The track bar, drag link, control arms, shocks, springs and sway bar all move when your suspension travels, so they're all suspect. Check the axle ends first, as they are most exposed to water that can wash away grease. For the greasable ones, use your grease gone and grease them, for the others, you'll have to remove the bolt, apply grease to the rubber bushing and reassemble.

U-joints can squeak when they get older, but that usually causes a rotational sound, as will a bad wheel bearing or brake issue.

If it's none of those things, it could also be a simple as a loose bolts in your bumper or somewhere else that's allowing to parts that shouldn't move to rub against with heavy movement, but given it's happening at slow speeds, I'd check those tie rod ends and bushings first.

Comment: Again, great answer.

Comment: Come by chat sometime.  Super active during the week.     http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop